# SharePoint: How do I create a new list from a list template?

Tags: sharepoint, list, moss, list-template

I've created a list template based on an Issue list and it is saved in the List Template Gallery. Now how do I create a new list based on this template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably just took a while for the timer job to fire.

The template eventually showed up as an option under `Lists > Create > Tracking section` after a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

```
string internalName = "MyListTemplateName";
SPListTemplate t = null;
    foreach (SPListTemplate template in web.ListTemplates)
     {
       if (template.InternalName.Equals(internalName)
       {
          t = template;
          break;
       }
    }    
        web.Lists.Add("nameoflist", "description", t);
```

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same situation today.
I saved a list as a template and i wanted to use that template in a new list.
On Sharepoint 2013, go to *Site Contents > Add an App >* 
 
Scroll down and you will see a page numbering saying that you are on page *1*
Click on the second page and all your saved templates will be there

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that Johan Leino's answer is marked as useful multiple times as it doesn't work in this particular case. If you create a template yourself, `web.ListTemplates` does not store it and you won't be able to create the list. It's only working for out-of-the-box templates.
If you want to create a list based on your custom template you need to do it this way:

```
SPListTemplateCollection listTemplates = web.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(web);
SPListTemplate listTemplate = listTemplates["MyCustomTemplate"];
Guid listId = web.Lists.Add("My New List Name", "My Description", listTemplate);
if (listId != null) { //all good }
```